# Trane XV95 thermostat wiring

Tags: thermostat

I have a Trane XV95 two stage furnace, wired up to a single stage thermostat. The W1 and W2 ports on the furnace are jumpered. Currently has a 4 wire cable. I'm trying to figure out if it's worth running a new 8 wire cable and getting a 2 stage thermostat to control this... or if I should just leave well enough alone. If I do run a new cable, I'd like to have a C wire, I assume that just hooks up to the "B/C" port I see on the furnace?

[[image: Furnace Wiring][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsHBJ.jpg)

[image: Thermostat Wiring]

Comment: Do you have an idea of the heat load of your house? (From a Manual J calculation, usually)

Comment: I don't... Spokane area, if it helps. Home is 2000 sq ft, well insulated, and the furnace is a TUH2B060A9V3VAA.